# Given an array of n numbers find all the ways of inserting "+" and "-" between them so that the result of the expression is positive

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

Given an array of `n` numbers find all the ways of inserting `+` and `-`  between them so that the result of the expression is positive.

I've found this problem recently and I thought it was interesting, but I'm not exactly sure how to solve it. I think I should try backtracking, no?
Any help or hints are deeply appreciated!

Edit: Would this be a correct solution? (I wrote it in python)

```py
def outputSolution(list):
    print(list)

def solution(x, dim):
    return len(x) == dim-1

def consistent(list, array):
    partial_sum = array[0]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] == 0:
            partial_sum = partial_sum - array[i+1]
        if list[i] == 1:
            partial_sum = partial_sum + array[i+1]
            
    absolute_remaining_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(list)+1, len(array)): #the remaining elements in array
        absolute_remaining_sum =absolute_remaining_sum + abs(array[i])
        
    if partial_sum + absolute_remaining_sum < 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
            
    

def solve(list, array):
    """
    array - the array of n given integers
    list -  the candidate to a solution
    """
    
    dim = len(array)
    
    for el in range(2): # el = 0 or 1 (0 for - and 1 for +)
        if len(list) < dim - 1:
            list.append(el)
            if consistent(list, array):
                if solution(list, dim):
                    outputSolution(list)
                solve(list[:], array)
            list.pop()

        
solve([], array)
```

My thought process was that there are n-1 gaps between those numbers. Each gap can have a '+' or a '-' in it. And so I build a list where list[i] is equal with 0 if between array[i] and array[i+1] there is an "-", and list[i] is equal with 0 if between array[i] and array[i+1] there is an "+". And I generated all the possible ways of choosing the values in the list, then I checked if that possible candidate is consistent or not. And I said that if the partial sum (calculated using the + and - in our current list) added to the maximum sum of the remaining elements of the given array is a negative number, then the candidate is inconsistent. If the candidate is consistent and it has the required length, then I said that it is a solution.

For example, if I had the array "array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" as input, I was given the following solutions:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Do you need to enumerate them or just count them?

Comment: Enumerate them too, I think @DavidEisenstat

Comment: If you have `n` numbers then you have `n-1` gaps between those numbers.  Each gap can have a '+' or a '-' in it.  With only two options you can use the `n-1` bit binary numbers to cover all possible arrangements: 0000 -> ----; 0001 -> ---+; 0010 -> --+- etc. up to 1111 -> ++++ Step through all the numbers and test the result of each arrangement.

Comment: @rossum Thank you a lot! Would this count as backtracking? I'm wondering because I recently discovered backtracking and I'm trying to learn more

Comment: The order of the values (aside from the first) is not relevant to the sum.  Sorting them first would allow one to avoid 2^(n-1) iterations.

Comment: @aneys, are the values `int` or `double`?  Are values ever zero? are values ever negative?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The values are int, they can be zero, but not negative

Comment: Actually I think they can also be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtracking is indeed a reasonable strategy. Since you need to enumerate, there's only one pruning trick that makes an asymptotic difference. Suppose that the array starts with a very large negative number, e.g.,

```
−50 10 10 10 10 1 2 3 4 5
```

The sum always includes a −50 term, so the sign for each 10 must be positive since otherwise the remaining numbers aren't large enough to make the overall sum positive. By making the example bigger (more and bigger numbers), we can create an exponential gap between the complexity of naive backtracking and the number of solutions.

If we implement the usual depth-first backtracking strategy and maintain the sum of the absolute values of the remaining array elements, then we can prune every node where the partial sum plus the sum of absolute values is not positive. Since every node not pruned yields at least one solution, we end up with an optimal output-sensitive time complexity.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: So would this me a correct solution? Edit: I can't copy and paste here, so I will edit my original post